# Mongoose populate method not populating all fields after updating document

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate

**I change the order of an array and then populate doesn't work. It still works on the documents that I did not try to update.**

I have a seccion model with preguntas inside of it

SECCION MODEL

```
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const seccionSchema = new Schema({
  titulo: { type: String },
  preguntas: [
    {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Pregunta',
    },
  ],
});
```

PREGUNTA MODEL

```
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const preguntaSchema = new Schema({
  titulo: { type: String, required: true },
});
```

A "Seccion" document with 2 "preguntas" looks something like this:

```
{
    "preguntas": [
        "5fb0a48ccb68c44c227a0432",
        "5fb0a48ccb68c44c227a0433"
    ],
    "_id": "5fb0a50fcb68c44c227a0436",
    "titulo": "Seccion 2",
    "__v": 3
}
```

**What I want to do is change the order in the preguntas array**, so that the _ids end up being [33, 32] instead of [32, 33] (last two digits of the _ids). I can update using ".save()" method or ".findOneAndUpdate()". **Here is the code using "findOneAndUpdate":**

```
router.put('/:id', async (req, res) => {
  const seccionId = req.params.id;
  try {
    const seccion = await Seccion.findOneAndUpdate(
      { _id: seccionId },
      { preguntas: ['5fb0a48ccb68c44c227a0433', '5fb0a48ccb68c44c227a0432'] },
      { new: true }
    );
    res.json(seccion);
  } catch (err) {
    res.json({ message: err });
  }
});
```

**The result works (and the order is changed in mongo atlas):**

```
{
    "preguntas": [
        "5fb0a48ccb68c44c227a0433",
        "5fb0a48ccb68c44c227a0432"
    ],
    "_id": "5fb0a50fcb68c44c227a0436",
    "titulo": "Seccion 2",
    "__v": 4
}
```

But when I try to use the **"populate()"** method of mongoose, **only one of the "preguntas ids" or none are populated** (below only the "pregunta" with id ending in 32 was populated):

```
{
    "preguntas": [
        {
            "_id": "5fb0a48ccb68c44c227a0432",
            "titulo": "Pregunta 3",
            "__v": 0
        }
    ],
    "_id": "5fb0a50fcb68c44c227a0436",
    "titulo": "Seccion 2",
    "__v": 4
}
```

So my guess is that the populate method is not working correctly, but **it does work on the other "Seccion" documents where I have not tryed to change the order** of the "preguntas" inside the array. Here is the code that uses the "populate" method:

```
router.get('/:id', async (req, res) => {
  const seccionId = req.params.id;
  try {
    const seccion = await Seccion.findById(seccionId).populate('preguntas');
    res.json(seccion);
  } catch (err) {
    res.json({ message: err });
  }
});
```

It has been really hard to make the populate work, **I really appreciate anyone's help**

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that pregunta of id `5fb0a48ccb68c44c227a0433` exists in the preguntas collection?

The way populate works is that it does a second `find` operation on the `preguntas` collection with the ids in the array, if a document is not found, it will be omitted from the array.

The issue is probably that the one ending with `33` does not exist in the preguntas collection.

Comment: The id ending with 33 does exist (double checked), I can even see the result of another document that uses that same id but does not populate it. I also made an update by hand directly on mongo atlas, changing the order of ids of a new "Seccion" document and "populate" also doesn't work when changeing by hand the ids :/

Comment: I believe it might be that each index in the array of ids has a pointer or reference and if you change the id, it points to the old id. Because when I changed back the order of ids it worked again